# Swing splash screen not working, Unexpected result

Tags: java, swing

Downloaded some code to display Splash Screen from O'Reilly, but When I do some modified some text to display as per need.

I did some investigation, and debug the program but found nothing.

Is that any windows platform issue?

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JWindow;
public class SplashScreen extends JWindow {
  private int duration;
  byte[] msg = new byte[]{65,112,114,105,108,32,70, 111, 111,108};
  String text = "";

  public SplashScreen(int d) {
    duration = d;    
  }

  // A simple little method to show a title screen in the center
  // of the screen for the amount of time given in the constructor
  public void showSplash() throws Exception {
    JPanel content = (JPanel)getContentPane();
    content.setBackground(Color.white);

    // Set the window's bounds, centering the window
    int width = 450;
    int height =300;
    Dimension screen = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    int x = (screen.width-width)/2;
    int y = (screen.height-height)/2;
    setBounds(x,y,width,height);

    JLabel txt = new JLabel
              (new String(msg), JLabel.CENTER);
    txt.setFont(new Font("Sans-Serif", Font.BOLD, 32));
    // Build the splash screen
    JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("oreilly.gif"));
    JLabel copyrt = new JLabel
      (new String(msg), JLabel.CENTER);


    URL url = new URL("http://findicons.com/files/icons/360/emoticons/128/satisfied.png");
    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(url);
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(img);
    JLabel iconL = new JLabel(icon);



    copyrt.setFont(new Font("Sans-Serif", Font.BOLD, 12));
    content.add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    content.add(txt, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    content.add(iconL, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    content.add(copyrt, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    Color oraRed = new Color(156, 20, 20,  255);
    content.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(oraRed, 10));

    // Display it
    setVisible(true);

    // Wait a little while, maybe while loading resources
    try { Thread.sleep(duration); } catch (Exception e) {}

    setVisible(false);
  }

  public void showSplashAndExit() {
    try {
        showSplash();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.exit(0);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Throw a nice little title page up on the screen first
    SplashScreen splash = new SplashScreen(10000);
    // Normally, we'd call splash.showSplash() and get on with the program.
    // But, since this is only a test...
    splash.showSplashAndExit();
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem? This works for me;

Comment: How many components are you adding to the center position of a `BorderLayout`?  `BorderLayout` can only manage one. Also, you can use `pack` and `setLocationRelativeTo(null)` to center the window

Comment: Answer: Change layout managers

Comment: Have you considered to use [SplashScreen](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html) native?

Comment: It was  working... "It was the April Fool welcome screen" :)